# BigQuery + Google Analytics data: Why is totals.TransactionRevenue multiplied by 10 ^ 6 as per the Schema...?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm checking Google Analytics schema on BQ and it seems the totals.TransactionRevenue value is automatically multiplied by 10^6. What would be the benefit of doing so?
Thanks.

[https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is most likely to give you ability to work with fraction of cents - like 2.401234 - as an INT64 2401234 without loosing the precision and rounding "surprises" related to FLOAT64